# TFS Team Administrator - deny right to add members?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS you can create teams. You can also assign [Administrators to those teams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409274.aspx). As a Team Administrator they can do a lot of things specific to the team, which is great.

I would like a Team Administrator to do all those things *except* "Add a team administrator" or "Add team members".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One needs "Edit project-level information" permission to add new users to TFS group. If you want to disable that team administrator the permission to add users, please do set Deny to "Edit project-level information" permission explicitly.

Go to the Security page, select that administrator and set "Edit project-level information" to Deny.

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to work. I added a user as a Team Administrator on the Team Profile page. I Deny "Edit project-level information" like your example. They can still add new users to the team. However, it did stop the user from changing iteration and area. Is the users admin access cached?